# Dealing with implicit typeclass conflict

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I'm trying to deal with an ambiguous implicits problem, and (relatedly) figure out what best practise should be for parameterizing typeclasses. I have a situation where I am using a typeclass to implement a polymorphic method. I initially tried the approach below:

```
abstract class IsValidTypeForContainer[A]
object IsValidTypeForContainer {
  implicit val IntIsValid = new IsValidTypeForContainer[Int] {}
  implicit val DoubleIsValid = new IsValidTypeForContainer[Double] {}
}

abstract class IsContainer[A, B: IsValidTypeForContainer] {
  def getElement(self: A, i: Int): B
  def get[R](self: A, ref: R)(implicit gets: GetsFromContainerMax[A, R, B]): gets.Out = gets.get(self, ref)
  def fromList(self: A, other: List[B]): A = ???
}
implicit class IsContainerOps[A, B: IsValidTypeForContainer](self: A)(implicit 
  isCont: IsContainer[A, B],
) {
  def getElement(i: Int) = isCont.getElement(self, i)
  def get[R](ref: R)(implicit gets: GetsFromContainerMax[A, R, B]): gets.Out = isCont.get(self, ref)
  def fromList(other: List[B]): A = isCont.fromList(self, other)
}

abstract class GetsFromContainerMax[A, R, B: IsValidTypeForContainer] {
  type Out
  def get(self: A, ref: R): Out
}
object GetsFromContainerMax {
  type Aux[A, R, B, O] = GetsFromContainerMax[A, R, B] { type Out = O }
  def instance[A, R, B: IsValidTypeForContainer, O](func: (A, R) => O): Aux[A, R, B, O] = new GetsFromContainerMax[A, R, B] {
    type Out = O
    def get(self: A, ref: R): Out = func(self, ref)
  }
  implicit def getsForListInt[A, B: IsValidTypeForContainer](implicit 
    isCons: IsContainer[A, B],
  ): Aux[A, List[Int], B, A] = instance(
    (self: A, ref: List[Int]) => {
      val lst = ref.map(isCons.getElement(self, _)).toList
      isCons.fromList(self, lst)
    }
  )
}
```

Where I have given the `GetsContainerMax` typeclass three parameters - one for the `IsContainer` object, one for the reference and one for the data type of the `IsContainer` object.

When I then try to use this, I get a compile error:

```
case class List1[B: IsValidTypeForContainer] (
  data: List[B]
)
implicit def list1IsContainer[B: IsValidTypeForContainer] = new IsContainer[List1[B], B] {
  def getElement(self: List1[B], i: Int): B = self.data(i)
  def fromList(self: List1[B], other: List[B]): List1[B] = ???
}

val l1 = List1[Int](List(1,2,3))
implicitly[IsContainer[List1[Int], Int]].get(l1, List(1,2)) // Works
implicitly[List1[Int] => IsContainerOps[List1[Int], Int]] // Works
l1.get(List(1,2)) // Does not work
```

If I use the -Xlog-implicits build parameter, it tells me that

```
ambiguous implicit values: both value IntIsValid in object IsValidTypeForContainer of type example.Test.IsValidTypeForContainer[Int] and value DoubleIsValid in object IsValidTypeForContainer of type example.Test.IsValidTypeForContainer[Double] match expected type example.Test.IsValidTypeForContainer[B]
```

Which seems to make sense; presumably I am bringing both of these implicits into scope by parameterizing the typeclass with the generic `B`.

My next thought was therefore to try to reduce the number of generic parameters for `IsValidTypeForContainer` to the minimum, in order to have only one typeclass in scope per type of `R`, likeso:

```
abstract class GetsFromContainerMin[R] {
  type Out
  def get[A](self: A, ref: R)(implicit isCont: IsContainer[A, _]): Out
}
object GetsFromContainerMin {
  type Aux[R, O] = GetsFromContainerMin[R] { type Out = O }
  def instance[A, R, O](func: (A, R) => O): Aux[R, O] = new GetsFromContainerMin[R] {
    type Out = O
    def get(self: A, ref: R)(implicit isCont: IsContainer[A, _]): Out = func(self, ref)
  }
  implicit def getsForListInt[A](implicit isCons: IsContainer[A, _]): Aux[List[Int], A] = instance(
    (self: A, ref: List[Int]) => {
      val lst = ref.map(isCons.getElement(self, _)).toList
      isCons.fromList(self, lst) // type mismatch - found: List[Any], required: List[_$3]
    }
  )
}
```

But this seems to not only not solve the problem, but to generate an additional error in that the compiler can no longer type-check that type B implements `IsValidTypeForContainer`.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

So I've messed around with this a bit and seem to have found the solution. The typeclass-with-three-parameters approach works, if I use

```
implicit class IsContainerOps[A, B](self: A)(implicit 
  isCont: IsContainer[A, B],
)
```

instead of

```
implicit class IsContainerOps[A, B: IsValidTypeForContainer](self: A)(implicit 
  isCont: IsContainer[A, B],
)
```

I am not exactly sure why this is and if anyone would care to respond I'd be interested to know. Are multiple typeclasses created if you use a context bound like in the original example, one for each implementation of `IsValidTypeForContainer`?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `GetsFromContainerMin`, only type classes without polymorphic methods can have constructor method `instance` (in companion object) because of the lack of polymorphic functions in Scala 2. In Scala 3 you'll be able to write

```
def instance[R, O](func: [A] => (A, R) => O): Aux[R, O] = ...
```

So far you have to write

```
object GetsFromContainerMin {
    type Aux[R, O] = GetsFromContainerMin[R] { type Out = O }

    implicit def getsForListInt[A](implicit isCons: IsContainer[A, _]): Aux[List[Int], A] = new GetsFromContainerMin[List[Int]] {
      override type Out = A
      override def get[A1](self: A1, ref: List[Int])(implicit isCont: IsContainer[A1, _]): Out = {
        val lst = ref.map(isCons.getElement(self, _)).toList
//                                          ^^^^
        isCons.fromList(self, lst)
//                      ^^^^
      }
    }
  }
```

I guess compile errors are pretty clear

```
type mismatch;
 found   : self.type (with underlying type A1)
 required: A
```

Regarding your first question,

```
implicit class IsContainerOps[A, B: IsValidTypeForContainer](self: A)(implicit
  isCont: IsContainer[A, B]   
)
```

is desugared to

```
implicit class IsContainerOps[A, B](self: A)(implicit
  ev: IsValidTypeForContainer[B],
  isCont: IsContainer[A, B]
)
```

but order of implicits is significant. If you modify `IsContainerOps` to

```
implicit class IsContainerOps[A, B](self: A)(implicit
  isCont: IsContainer[A, B],
  ev: IsValidTypeForContainer[B],
)
```

then `l1.get(List(1,2))` will compile.

Implicits are resolved from left to right. **You want** firstly `A` to be inferred (from `self`), then `IsContainer[A, B]` to be resolved, so `B` to be inferred and `IsValidTypeForContainer[B]` to be resolved **and not vice versa** firstly `A` to be inferred, then `IsValidTypeForContainer[B]` to be resolved, and at this step `B` is not restricted, there is no connection between `A` and `B`, so possibly `B` can be not inferred or inferred to be `Nothing`, so `IsContainer[A, B]` is not resolved. I'm a little simplifying (not every time when you swap implicits you break resolution) but general strategy of implicit resolution and type inference is as I described.

Comment: thank you for this, as ever. So, it seems like it is generally better/necessary to have the typeclass fully parameterized with generics (like GetFromContainerMax), rather than partially parameterized (like GetFromContainerMin).

Comment: @Chrisper No. Look at such type classes as `Functor`, `Monad`, `Applicative`, `Foldable`, `Traversable`... They have type parameters both on trait level and on method level. You just should do things correctly.